# How to remove unassigned entities in JPA?

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

I have a database including entities like Tag and Item. One item may have many tags and one tag can be assigned to many items, therefore @ManyToMany relation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="items")
public class Item {

    ...other fields...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "items_tags", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

and what I'm trying to do is to remove Tags from database based corresponding checkbox selection on .xhtml page. The first method I tried was:

```
public void deleteTags(List<Tag> selectedTags) {
    for (Tag tag : selectedTags) {
        em.remove(em.merge(tag));
        }
    }
```

which works only if all selectedTags were unassigned to any Item. In other case method crashes and nothing is removed, so I tried this workaround:

```
@EJB
private ItemsServices is;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

...stuff...

public void deleteTags(List<Tag> selectedTags) {
    List<Item> items = is.getItems();

        for (Tag tag : selectedTags) {
            for (Item i : items) {
                if(i.getTags().contains(tag)) {
                    // Do some popup
                } else {
                   em.remove(em.merge(tag));
                }
            }
       }
 }
```

But well, it's not working either. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why the `if... else ...` condition? You want to remove a `Tag` regardless of whether it is used by an `Item` or not. Try the following code:

```
for (Tag tag : selectedTags) {
    Tag persistentTag = em.find(Tag.class, tag.getId());
    for (Item item : is.findByTag(persistentTag)) {
        item.getTags().remove(persistentTag);
    }
    em.remove(persistentTag);
}
```

Comment: I don't seem to have findByTag method, how should it look like?

Comment: Well, I guess it should be a method executing a query like `SELECT i FROM Item i WHERE :tag MEMBER OF i.tags`. You could also add a `JOIN FETCH i.tags` clause to optimize the query